# how to declare 2 dimensional array with known number of cols and unknown number of rows

Tags: python

as shown in the code posted below i am trying to declare nx14 dimensional array. i do not know how many rows i would have but i know that for each row there will be 14 values to be entered.
please let me know how to achieve that correctly

**code**:

```
rowOfGridCells = []

...
...
...

for row in range(startRowIndex,maxHeightOfElevationsTIFF,verticalStep):
    
    rowOfGridCells.append([])
    rowOfGridCells[row//10][0].append(rowOfGridCellsClassifications)
    
    rowOfGridCells.append([])
    rowOfGridCells[row//10][1].append(rowOfNDVIsTIFFDetails)
    
    rowOfGridCells.append([])
    rowOfGridCells[row//10][2].append(rowOfCenterPointInEPSG4326)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a basic Python solution? Because common third party packages like `numpy` and `pandas` might be a lot more efficient and easier to use here. Also, you're asking about arrays, but are declaring a list - it would be good if you could provide a bit more information about what type of data you're looking to store in the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for row in range(int(input()))]
```